# Emitting SIGINT event from inside node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently working with a library in node.js that happens to capture Ctrl-C and throw an error instead of allowing the normal behaviour (emitting a SIGINT event) to occur.

Wondering if it is possible to catch this error and emit a SIGINT event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to do this within a Node process.

You can emit the `'SIGINT'` event from the process object.

```
process.emit('SIGINT');
```

Comment: Tried testing it and it doesn't seem to work :( 

Using node v5.6.0, if that's any help

Comment: Using this code to test:

https://gist.github.com/rohanorton/33db9fcbce494eab796c

Comment: Lol, I tried that first and couldn't get it to work, but it works a charm now! Must be going mad! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

The best approach would be to use the [`process.kill`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal) function.

From docs:

> The process.kill() method sends the signal to the process identified by pid.

Example:

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  console.log('Got SIGINT signal.');
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Exiting.');
  process.exit(0);
}, 100);

process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGINT');
```